# How to dynamically change area color based on y-axis values in ApexCharts Area Chart?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am trying to create a colour temperature `area` chart where the area colour charges based on the y-axis value.

I can get it working for `line` chart. [Here is a live codebox reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/apexcharts-vue3-rounded-corners-forked-z6z4qq?file=/src/Chart.vue). And here is a screenshot:

[image]

But when I change it to an `area` chart it stops working. The area colour is no longer based on the y-axis value. [Here is a live codebox reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/apexcharts-vue3-rounded-corners-forked-ymjgns?file=/src/Chart.vue). And here is a screenshot:

[image]

What I actually want is something like this, it's just a shitty drawing but you get the idea:

[image]

So how do I create an `area` chart where the area colour is based on the y-axis value?

P.S. I am using the [vue3-apexcharts wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-apexcharts) but it should be the same for all apexcharts.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is more difficult that it may seem.

You want the fill color to have a *horizontal* gradient, but the
color stops of this gradient to have values corresponding to the
`y` (vertical value) of the function.

This is complicated further more by the fact that current
apexcharts API doesn't offer access to pixel values of the
curves nor to the value-to-pixel functions of the axes.

The only remaining option is to access the generated svg,
to identify the curve's PATH there, to use the pixel
values of that PATH and then to replicate the color computing
function of the linear gradient to find the corresponding
color stops.

Here's a first implementation of those ideas in vanilla JS
that may set you in the right direction.

```js
const NColorStops = 40;
const options = {
    series: [
        {
            name: "Rank",
            data: [
                {x: "1/12/2023", y: 44},
                {x: "2/12/2023", y: 5},
                {x: "3/12/2023", y: 41},
                {x: "4/12/2023", y: 67},
                {x: "5/12/2023", y: 22},
                {x: "6/12/2023", y: 43},
            ],
        },
    ],
    chart: {
        type: "area",
        events: {
            animationEnd: updateColors
        },
        toolbar: {
            show: false,
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: false,
        },
    },
    xaxis: {
        type: "category",
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        reversed: true,
        labels: {
            formatter: (value) => {
                if(value === 0){
                    return "1";
                }
                else if(value === 100){
                    return "100+";
                }
                else{
                    return value.toFixed(0);
                }
            },
        },
    },
    stroke: {
        //show: false,
        curve: "smooth",
        lineCap: "round",
    },
    fill: {
        type: "gradient",
        gradient: {
            type: "horizontal",
            colorStops: Array.from({length: NColorStops}, (_, i) => ({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                offset: i / (NColorStops - 1) * 100
            }))
        },
    },
    plotOptions: {area: {fillTo: "end"}},
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
    }
};

const ch = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart1'), options);
ch.render();

const verticalColorStops = [
    {
        offset: 10,
        color: "#66bb6a",
        opacity: 1,
    },
    {
        offset: 30,
        color: "#ffca28",
        opacity: 1,
    },
    {
        offset: 50,
        color: "#ffa726",
        opacity: 1,
    },
    {
        offset: 70,
        color: "#ef5350",
        opacity: 1,
    },
];

function interpolateVerticalColorStops(percent){
    let i = 0;
    while(i < verticalColorStops.length && percent > verticalColorStops[i].offset){
        i++;
    }
    if(i === 0){
        return verticalColorStops[i].color;
    }
    if(i >= verticalColorStops.length){
        return verticalColorStops[verticalColorStops.length - 1].color;
    }
    return combineColors(percent - verticalColorStops[i - 1].offset, verticalColorStops[i - 1].color,
        verticalColorStops[i].offset - percent, verticalColorStops[i].color);
}

function combineColors(fact1, col1, fact2, col2){ // assume colors in #ffaa90 format
     return '#'+(Math.round(((parseInt(col1.substring(1, 3), 16) * fact2 +
         parseInt(col2.substring(1, 3), 16) * fact1) / (fact1 + fact2)))).toString(16) +
         (Math.round(((parseInt(col1.substring(3, 5), 16) * fact2 +
         parseInt(col2.substring(3, 5), 16) * fact1) / (fact1 + fact2)))).toString(16) +
         (Math.round(((parseInt(col1.substring(5), 16) * fact2 +
         parseInt(col2.substring(5), 16) * fact1) / (fact1 + fact2)))).toString(16);
}

function updateColors(){
    const svg = ch.getChartArea();
    const series1Paths = Array.from(svg.getElementsByClassName('apexcharts-series')[0].getElementsByTagName('path'));
    const curvePath = series1Paths.filter(p => p.getAttribute('fill') !== 'none')[0];
    const totalLength = curvePath.getTotalLength();
    let lenCursorLeft = 0, pointLeft = null, pointCurrent = curvePath.getPointAtLength(lenCursorLeft),
        yMax = pointCurrent.y;
    const xMin = pointCurrent.x;
    do{
        pointLeft = pointCurrent;
        lenCursorLeft++;
        pointCurrent = curvePath.getPointAtLength(lenCursorLeft);
    }while(pointCurrent.x - xMin < 1);
    lenCursorLeft--;

    let lenCursorRight = totalLength, pointRight = null;
    pointCurrent = curvePath.getPointAtLength(lenCursorRight);
    yMax = Math.max(yMax, pointCurrent.y);
    const xMax = pointCurrent.x;
    do{
        pointRight = pointCurrent;
        lenCursorRight--;
        pointCurrent = curvePath.getPointAtLength(lenCursorRight);
    }while(xMax - pointCurrent.x < 1);
    lenCursorRight++;

    const xTarget = Array.from({length: NColorStops}, (_, i) => xMin + (i + 0.5) * (xMax - xMin) / (NColorStops - 1));
    const cursorTarget = Array.from({length: NColorStops}, (_, i) => lenCursorLeft + (i + 0.5) * (lenCursorRight - lenCursorLeft) / (NColorStops - 1));
    const points = cursorTarget.map(cursor => curvePath.getPointAtLength(cursor));
    for(let i = 0; i < NColorStops; i++){
        let kk = 0;
        let delta = points[i].x - xTarget[i];
        while((delta > 1 || -delta > 1) && kk++ < 5){
            cursorTarget[i] -= delta;
            points[i] = curvePath.getPointAtLength(cursorTarget[i]);
            delta = points[i].x - xTarget[i];
        }
    }
    const yPercent = points.map(p =>  p.y / yMax * 100);
    const colors = yPercent.map(interpolateVerticalColorStops);

    const linearGradient = ch.getChartArea().getElementsByTagName('linearGradient')[0];
    const stops = linearGradient.getElementsByTagName('stop')
    Array.from(stops).forEach((stop, i) => stop.setAttribute('stop-color', colors[i]));
}
```

```html
<div id="chart1"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.41.1/apexcharts.min.js"  integrity="sha512-Gpg0M5UOTFSHGglemXUOUzL1LyO8MT0fxmEAjGN8jNlY6oSOsLerF1/vuXrqJXKyV5QIay12trwDDhmRJHZisA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The same with vue3, in a [fork of the question codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apexcharts-vue3-rounded-corners-forked-8l8c4q?file=/src/Chart.vue), using [emitted events](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/20#issuecomment-881142984) instead of those defined in the configuration object, that don't work with vue.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah the events for the Vue wrapper don't work inside the `charts` object. You have to define them in the template like `<apexchart  :options="options"  :series="series" @markerClick="handleClick" />`. See [this issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue3-apexcharts/issues/20) for full details.